# Spotify Multiple Tracks Lookup

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm using the Spotify API and I need to make a multiple IDs lookup (maybe using a trackset)

This is the default URL pattern, but, I can pass only one ID to the uri field

> [http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:track:6NmXV4o6bmp704aPGyTVVG](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify%3atrack:6NmXV4o6bmp704aPGyTVVG)

Is there a way I can lookup a trackset passing multiple IDS like we do on the playlist widget?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) there is [an endpoint for fetching several tracks at once](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-tracks/).

If you are currently using the Metadata API, it may be worth it checking the [migration guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/migration-guide/).

Comment: Hello, I'm late with my answer but at that time I migrated to the Web API and everything worked fine. Thank you very much